# Checkstyle and Maven's Standard Directory Layout

Tags: maven, checkstyle

I'm following Maven's [Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) for my project.

**Is there a preferred directory to put my checkstyle.xml file**? I've seen it on at least 3 possible locations:

- src/main/resources/checkstyle.xml
- src/main/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml - Example: [Joda-Time](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/blob/master/src/main/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml)
- src/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml - Example: [Spring Boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-parent/src/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml)

Since this is mostly a file for developers, the first option gives me doubts. Would it make sense to include checkstyle.xml into the JAR file?

Thanks,

Fede

Comment: `src/main/resources` does not make sense, cause it's copied during the build process and may be (based on the particular configuration filtered) which is not a good idea...I would suggest to put it into `src/checkstyle` ...one of the rules is that everything which is in `src/main/` will be packaged...which is not necessary for checkstyle rules ?

Comment: Oh, so my hesitations about the first option would also apply to the second one (checkstyle file will be packaged). That makes sense. Add this as an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting `checkstyle.xml` in `src` directory doesn't really make sense, as it is not part of source code.

The most common convention I've observed in my projects is putting it into `config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml`. Thousands of projects use it ([filename:checkstyle.xml path:config/checkstyle](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=filename%3Acheckstyle.xml+path%3Aconfig%2Fcheckstyle&type=Code&ref=searchresults)) and Gradle uses this location [by default](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/checkstyle_plugin.html#N16A74).

Comment: I didn't know that about Gradle. Thank you